# Tweepy - How long can an API session be kept open

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I have a script that I want to keep running essentially indefinitely, what it does is monitor an API and send out a tweet if certain conditions are met. The script looks something like this

```
while True:
    #API CONDITION CHECKS HERE
    if api_condition_check:
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        tweet = "This is the tweet."
        if api.update_status(tweet):
            print "Tweet Succeeded"
    sleep(60)
```

The script sets a socket when running and has a cron job checking for a lock and restarting the script to handles crashes, sever reboots etc.

What I'm unsure of is if I can put the `api` creation element outside of the `while` loop that run perpetually, without that api object timing out or something. So essentially the code would look like this

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

while True:
    #API CONDITION CHECKS HERE
    if api_condition_check:
        tweet = "This is the tweet."
        if api.update_status(tweet):
            print "Tweet Succeeded"
    sleep(60)
```

The second way means the code isn't having to recreate the api object every time, however it could be hours between tweets and the code could run for weeks at a time assuming no errors or server problems so will the api object timeout if it's only created when the script starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the api object timeout if it's only created when the script starts?

In my experience, no.  All that Tweepy is doing is taking your keys & tokens and using that to sign any requests that you make.

The only problem comes if you (or your user) removes the authorisation by going to Twitter's settings and revoking the app.